# Create a dictionary from pandas empty dataframe with only column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-manipulation

I have a pandas data frame with only two column names( single row, which can be also considered as headers).I want to make a dictionary out of this with the first column being the value and the second column being the key.I already tried the
 `to.dict()` method, but it's not working as it's an empty dataframe.

**Example**
*df=|Land |Norway| to  {'Land': Norway}*

I can change the pandas data frame to some other type and find my way around it, but this question is mostly to learn the best/different/efficient approach for this problem.

For now I have this as the solution :

```
dict(zip(a.iloc[0:0,0:1],a.iloc[0:0,1:2]))
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Very manual solution

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Land', 'Norway'])

df = pd.DataFrame({df.columns[0]: df.columns[1]}, index=[0])
```

If you have any number of columns and you want each sequential pair to have this transformation, try:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(df.columns[::2], df.columns[1::2])), index=[0])
```

*Note: You will get an error if your `DataFrame` does not have at least two columns.*

Comment: I would like a general solution, something I can write inside a function

Comment: getting an error like this ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: @amarykya_ishtmella fixed - sorry about that

Comment: This is working, only that my data has only one row with two columns.(It's an empty dataframe. ''' dict(zip(a.iloc[0:0,0:1],a.iloc[0:0,1:2]))''' I'm using this

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way convert the columns to a list and a list to a dictionary

```py
def list_to_dict(a):
    it = iter(a)
    ret_dict = dict(zip(it, it))
    return ret_dict

df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['Land', 'Normway'])
dict_val = list_to_dict(df.columns.to_list())
dict_val # {'Land': 'Normway'}
```